# Why do I need to export the PATH to open VS Code from the Terminal every time I open a new window?

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal

I am used to opening VS Code from the terminal (iTerm2) using `code .`. This past week I got a new Mac and set it up just fine, except each time I want to use `code .` I have to provide the following code:

`export PATH="$PATH:/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin"`

Every time I open a new Terminal window, I have to do it again. Could anyone please offer some advice? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The export command adds that path to the PATH env variable, but only temporarily. If you want to add it permanently, check these 2 ways here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/829393/is-export-only-useful-for-temporary-effects

If you want to understand more about PATH, check here:
https://stackabuse.com/how-to-permanently-set-path-in-linux/

After adding "/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin" it should work fine.

Comment: Hi Daniel Gomes, welcome to stackoverflow! Thanks for submitting an answer. Because links can break over time, consider including a summary of the topics covered or the relevant snippets from the links you provided to help your answer remain helpful.